# Why does this regexp work as var pattern = / ... / but not as a var pattern = RegExp("...")?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="Jestem bardzo, bardzo zadowolony. Można powiedzieć, że jestem również uszczęśliwiony i uspokojony."; 

patt1=new RegExp( "\bi\b", "g"); //<--- (to find the single word: "i")

document.write(str.match(patt1));
</script>
```

It works well as `var pattern = /\bi\b/g;` but not when using `RegExp("\bi\b","g")`. Why? (...thank you in advance)

Answer (score 5):

\ is the escape character in JavaScript strings. It's *also* the escape character in regular expressions! Since you're passing a string to [the RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/RegExp), you have to escape the escape character...

```
patt1=new RegExp( "\\bi\\b", "g");
```

Comment: And if you're writing your JS out with PHP you need to TRIPLE it, as I just spent three hours finding out.  echo '<script>patt1=new RegExp( "\\\bi\\\b", "g");</script>'